# How to create subrows of a row in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I want to insert data into a dataframe like the image below with only CSV module in Python.
Is there any way to split rows this way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should think in terms of what is a csv file rather than the python csv module.
CSV files are nothing more than text representations of flat tables, therefore your sub-categories and sub-totals require separate rows.
If you want to create an object with a list of <sub-category, sub-total> pairs you have to parse the rows accordingly.

First you read a category and a total frequency and create the new category object, then until category stays the same you can add <sub-category, sub-total> pairs to its sub-categories list.
With the assumptions that category is unique and that there is an header row, you could try something like this:

```
import csv

with open('cats.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['category', 'total', 'sub-category', 'sub-total']
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    lastCat = ""
    nextCat = ""

    row = next(csv_reader) # I'm skipping the first line
  
    row = next(csv_reader, '')
    while True:  
        if row == '':
            break

        nextCat = row['category']
        lastCat = nextCat

        newCategory = Category.fromCSV(row) # This is just an example
        while nextCat == lastCat:
            newCategory.addData(row)

            row = next(csv_reader, '')
            if row == '':
                break

            nextCat = row['category']
```

I didn't test my code, so I don't recommend you to use as something more than a suggestion